# Finding Column Number using OpenCSV

Tags: java, opencsv

I am using openCSV package in Java to create CSVs. I am creating a CSV with two columns. First Column represents first name of a person. Second Column represents second name of a person. So, it is like

```
 Deepak, Prasath
 Rakesh, Mehra
 Prakash, Merhra
```

Now, what I want to do is : If someone tries to add Deepak Kumar like "Deepak,Kareem" . Then the script should be able to append to the existing record  like

```
 Deepak, Prasath, Kareem
```

Can any one help, how using OpenCSV package we can append to a particular row or column ?

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: No. I am new to this. I can write into CSV. But I cannot find out the specific row or column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a code which meets this requirement :

```
static CSVReader read = null;
static CSVWriter writer = null;
static String csvfile;
static List<String[]> arg = null;
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static List<String[]> readFile(CSVReader read, List<String[]> arg) throws IOException {
    arg = read.readAll();

    for (String[] lineTokens : arg) {
        for (String token : lineTokens) {
            System.out.print(token + ",");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return arg;
}

public static void write_to_csv(String command_input, String command_output, CSVWriter writer, String csvfile, List<String[]> arg) throws IOException {
    String[] count = (command_input + "," + command_output).split(",");
    String rename = (getFilename(csvfile) + "_part.csv");
    int i = 0;
    String[] tail;
    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(rename));
    for (String[] head : arg) {
        if (head[0].equals(command_input)) {

            i = 0;
            tail = new String[head.length + 1];
            for (String h : head) {
                tail[i] = h;
                System.out.println(h);
                i++;
            }
            tail[tail.length - 1] = command_output;
            writer.writeNext(tail);
        } else {
            i--;
            writer.writeNext(head);
        }
    }
    if(i < 0){
        writer.writeNext(count);
    }
    writer.close();
    File original = new File(rename);
    File gre = new File(csvfile);
    boolean fr = original.renameTo(gre);
    System.out.println(fr);
}

static {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter the file name");
        csvfile = in.nextLine();
        File file_exists = new File(csvfile);
        if (file_exists.exists()) {
            read = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
        } else {
            file_exists.createNewFile();
            read = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvfile));

        }
        arg = readFile(read, arg);
        read.close();
        if (file_exists.delete()) {
            System.out.println(file_exists.getName() + " is deleted.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Operation Failed");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DifferentApproach.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DifferentApproach.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static String getFilename(String csvfile) {
    String last[] = csvfile.split("\\.");//csvfile.split(".*(?=\\.)");
    return last[last.length - 2];
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        write_to_csv("mno", "Hi I am N Deepak Prasath", writer, csvfile, arg);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DifferentApproach.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the document and find the row where Deepak is. Then you get the text from the cell next to it and append your ",Kareem" to it, save the text into the cell afterwards.

Comment: But how will I achieve through OpenCSV ?

Comment: So you've actually asked for a solution to a problem you haven't even tried to solve? Hmph :-/

Comment: I am struck at that point, where I can append. The iteration part is easy. But I am not sure, how will I append to the row where the value is found.

Comment: You can allways read the whole file and print it again with one changed value... rewriting the original file. This isn't the best way but I haven't found a way how to update certain cell in OpenCsv.


Sounds like a bad practice though. Databases were made for this purpose... I usually use Excel to print one-time view on things or upload things. Not to store data and modify them.

Comment: Hi Lenymm, check the answer

Comment: Good job man! But to be honest I still don't see the point of doing something like that.

Comment: We have 34 commands which has got sub commands . So, We are creating a code which would run these 34 commands along with their sub options. We would execute this code after every version upgrade. 

For example - If there is a command named "A" and a subcommand "abc" , then it will get stored as A,abc,"<output> . If we execute the code again , then instead of creating a new row, we would just append the output of "A abc" to already existing row. The point being not creating duplicate rows. Still any doubt, sir ? :-)

Comment: Oh, yes, the code will also test for some random options too. Running the code one time will create around approx. 400 rows .